# Changing column name and finding mean and standard deviation in Spyder (Python 3.9.7)

Tags: python, rename, spyder, mean, standard-deviation

I'm working on a project for class, and y'all have been so incredibly helpful!

Anyways, I used this code:

`SO21= BI21[BI21["OnHand"].eq(0)].groupby("BrandID")["InventoryDate"].nunique()`

And it generated this series (please bare with me I'm still learning how to best input my information here for you to see):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFn0v.png)

I then wanted to find the sum, mean, standard deviation, and standard error and used this code that we learned in class:

```
SOSummary19 = SO19["InventoryDate"].agg(["sum","mean","std","sem"])
```

It returns a KeyError: "InventoryDate'

My goal is to take those measurements based on the numbers in the 'InventoryDate' Column from the image I posted, and I would also like to rename 'InventoryDate' to 'DaysStockedOut'

Thank you in advance for your help, you are ALL amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOSummary19= SO19.agg(["sum","mean","std","sem"]) Was the fix

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).